# Norms inequality in a sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let  $1 \leq p<q \leq \infty$ (p an q are not related)

Let $\Phi$ be the vector space of all sequences with at most finitely many nonzero elements, meaning $\Phi=\{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty|$ there is $n_o$ such that $x_n=0$ whenever $n\leq n_0\}$

i want to show that $\|x\|_q\leq \|x\|_p$ and there exist no C such that $\|x\|_p \leq C\|x\|_q$ by showing that $\sup_{0\neq x\in \Psi} \frac{\|x\|_p}{\|x\|_q}=\infty$

If $\|x\|_p=1$ then $|x_i|\leq 1 \forall x_i$ and then $|x_i|^q<|x_i|^p$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n_0} |x_i|^q \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n_0} |x_i|^p$. I am not sure if i can simply apply the roots hereon both sides. is this at all a correct direction?

Is there another way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to first observe that
$$ ||x||_{\infty}^p=\sup_n|x(n)|^p\leq \sum_{n}|x(n)|^p=||x||_p^p $$
hence $||x||_{\infty}\leq ||x||_p$. If $p<q<\infty$, then
$$||x||_q^q=\sum_n|x(n)|^q\leq ||x||_{\infty}^{q-p}\sum_n|x(n)|^p=||x||_{\infty}^{q-p}||x||_p^p\leq ||x||_p^q$$
with the last inequality using the $\infty$ case. Taking $q$th roots shows that $||x||_q\leq ||x||_p$.

To show that there is no constant $C$ such that $||x||_p\leq C||x||_q$, let $\{x_k\}$ be the sequence in $\Phi$ such that $x_k(n)=1$ for $1\leq n\leq k$ and $x_k(n)=0$ otherwise. Then
$$ ||x_k||_p=k^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
and
$$ ||x_k||_q=k^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
(with the convention $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$)
hence
$$\frac{||x_k||_p}{||x_k||_q}=k^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\to\infty$$
as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Very very helpful, teaching and informative. thanks a lot.